# phpmyadmin about utf8 char display

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, character-encoding

I have problem with `utf8` character display; some parts are displaying like this: `????????`

All unicodes in `phpmyadmin` are `utf8` general ci, so I just found out that I should add below code to my `lib.php` file:

```
mysql_query(“SET CHARACTER SET utf8″);
```

But where should I put this code?

Here is my **lib.php**

```
<?php
Class Database{
    public $host   = DB_HOST;
    public $user   = DB_USER;
    public $pass   = DB_PASS;
    public $dbname = DB_NAME;


    public $link;
    public $error;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->connectDB();
    }

    private function connectDB(){
    $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbname);
    if(!$this->link){
        $this->error ="Connection fail".$this->link->connect_error;
        return false;
    }
 }

    // Select or Read data

    public function select($query){
        $result = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            return $result;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Insert data
    public function insert($query){
    $insert_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
    if($insert_row){
        header("Location: index.php?msg=".urlencode('Data Inserted successfully.'));
        exit();
    } else {
        die("Error :(".$this->link->errno.")".$this->link->error);
    }
  }

    // Update data
    public function update($query){
    $update_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
    if($update_row){
        header("Location: index.php?msg=".urlencode('Data Updated successfully.'));
        exit();
    } else {
        die("Error :(".$this->link->errno.")".$this->link->error);
    }
  }

  // Delete data
   public function delete($query){
    $delete_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
    if($delete_row){
        header("Location: index.php?msg=".urlencode('Data Deleted successfully.'));
        exit();
    } else {
        die("Error :(".$this->link->errno.")".$this->link->error);
    }
  }



}
```

I read most relevant issues just I want to know where should I add code.

Comment: try to isolate the problem you are facing in less lines code.

Comment: try `$this->link->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');` in the select function before you run the actual query.

Comment: or better add `$this->link->set_charset("utf8");` as the last line of `function connectDB`

Comment: tnx - solved---> $this->link->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

Comment: tnx u guys , u are the best...